# GWT object graph from server is empty after save

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory, gwt2

When I create a new proxy on the client, with a list of new child proxies, and persist the graph to the server, I only get back the root node. I have verified that the server is correctly saving the graph and returning the graph, but GWT fails to load these as proxies on the client.

I have the models:

```
class TripProxy {
   List<PatronProxy> getPatrons();
   void setPatrons(List<PatronProxy> patrons);

   // some other fields
}

class PatronProxy {
   void setName(String name);
   String getName();
}
```

My editor creates a new trip where one or more patrons can be added to the trip. The save method looks something like:

```
Trip save(Trip trip);
```

Which simply saves what was given and returns it back. Why does the returned trip not include the Patrons that were attached? I am specifying a proper with(...) statement with my call to save. I know this because when I later edit the trip (after refreshing the browser) I am able to see the patrons.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're *"specifying a proper with(...) statement"* but can you show it?

Because the `with()` is only related to what's being returned from the server, your *"I know this because ..."* makes no sense: it only validates the fact that your objects have been saved, and the with() of your retrieval method is OK, not the with() of the save() method.

Your call to `save()` should look like:

```
ctx.save(tripProxy).with("patrons").to(new Receiver<TripProxy>() { ... });
```

(feel free to replace `to()` with `fire()` if you want to fire the context right there instead of later one)

Comment: My 'with' looks like: with("patrons", "origin", "destination"). Origin and destination are each AddressProxy's that are also newly created as well. These two properties are correctly returned from the server whereas the patrons property is not. My _because_ was referring to when the trip proxy was later fetched from the server on edit; not the actual saving after editing.

Comment: OK, I better understand now. Could you show your server code for the `Trip save(Trip trip)` method? Do you batch other methods in your `RequestContext`?

Comment: No, I dont batch but I think I found it. I usually try to simplify my problem when asking questions on SO and it looks like I simplified this one too much. When I looked at the save method again, I found the problem. Completely my fault. Thanks for you help!